# Erro ao programar em Haskell

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

Estou tendo muita dificuldade em entender os erros do Haskell no GHCI. Meu professor mandou umas questões e a primeira já veio pronta e eu colei no terminal:

```
        module Main (main) where
        main :: IO()
        main = do putStrLn "Digite um número"
                  n1<-readLn
                  putStrLn
                  n2<-readLn
                  putStr "Soma dos números digitados:"
                  putStrLn (show(n1+n2))
```

Ocorreram dois erros, esse é o primeiro:

```
        *Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' 
                     with actual type `String -> IO ()'
        *Probable cause: `putStrLn' is applied to too few arguments

         In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn
         In the expression:
           do putStrLn "Digite um número"
              n1 <- readLn
              putStrLn
              n2 <- readLn
          ....
        In an equation for `main':
            main
               = do putStrLn "Digite um número"
                 n1 <- readLn
                 putStrLn
                 ....
        |
    5   |        putStrLn               
        |
```

Segundo erro:

```
            * Couldn'match expected type ` (String -> IO ())
                                       -> String -> IO ()'
                     with actual type `IO ()'
            * The function `putStr' is applied to three arguments,
              but its type `String -> IO ()' has only one
              In a stmt of a 'do' block:
                putStr "Soma dos números digitados:" putStrLn (show (n1+n2))
              In the expression:
                do putStrLn "Digit um número"
                   n1 <- readLn
                   putStrLn
                   n2 <- readLn
      
                  ....
    
         | 
       7 |            putStr "Soma dos números digitados:"             
         |
```

Tmbém quero entender o uso do module Main (main) e se é necessário pois já achei exemplos de códigos sem ele.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro erro esta acontecendo porque a segunda chamada da função `putStrLn` espera uma `String` como parâmetro, você pode ver pela assinatura da função`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. Para resolver este erro, basta passar uma string  como parâmetro para a função, para ela ser exibida no terminal.

```hs
module Main (main) where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Digite um número"
  n1 <- readLn
  putStrLn "Digite outro número" -- Mensagem para ser exibida no terminal
  n2 <- readLn
  putStr "Soma dos números digitados:"
  putStrLn (show (n1 + n2))
```

O segundo erro, esta acontecendo por uma falta de formatação no código. Tente executar o código acima.